# How do I read in a file path from an XML file

Tags: java, xml, file, dom

I am trying to read in a file path from an XML file in java, but I am getting a file not found exception. I am not sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the XML file:

```
   <adapters>
        <adapter>
            <class>adapters.CSVFileAdapter</class>
            <properties>
               <property name="filename">C:\test.csv</property>
            </properties>
         </adapter>
         <adapter>
            <class>adapters.SNMPAdapter</class>
            <properties>
               <property name="target">10.100.85.135</property>
               <property name="port">134</property>
            </properties>
         </adapter>    
</adapters>
```

This is my java code:

```
public class XMLConfigurationReader {

public static List<String> load()
{
    List<String> adpList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try{

        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("C:/myProject/adapters.xml"));
        doc.normalize(); 

        NodeList rootNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("adapters");
        Node rootNode = rootNodes.item(0);
        Element rootElement = (Element) rootNode;
        rootNodes = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("class");

        for(int k=0; k<rootNodes.getLength(); k++){
            Node theAdapter = rootNodes.item(k);
            Element adpElement = (Element) theAdapter;
            adpList.add(adpElement.getTextContent());   
        }

         rootNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("properties");
        for (int i = 0; i < rootNodes.getLength(); i++) { // loop for properties
            Node nodeData = rootNodes.item(i);
            Element elementColumnDetails = (Element) nodeData;
            NodeList nodeListRow = elementColumnDetails.getElementsByTagName("property");
            for (int j = 0; j < nodeListRow.getLength(); j++) { // loop for property
                Node nodeRow = nodeListRow.item(j);
                Element elementRow = (Element) nodeRow;

                if(elementRow.getAttribute("property") != null){
                    String property = elementRow.getTextContent().trim();
                }

            }
        }

    }catch(ParserConfigurationException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return adpList;

}
```

}

Comment: is `C:/myProject/adapters.xml` path is correct ? and stack trace will also help.

Comment: yeh that path is definitely correct. It's not that that is the issue, I think it is because it is not reading in C:\test.csv from the XML file

Comment: @user3216736 do you get that exception on local machine or on environment?

Comment: Please try to use C:\ inseted of C:/ . (replacing '/' to '\')

Comment: Be better to write any path using `File.separator`

Comment: @user3216736 you can check very easely if your program can't find `test.csv`. Just do `new File("C:/test.csv")` and see whether you'll get `FileNotFound` Exception or not

Comment: You should seriously consider learning debugging techniques. This kind of errors can be spotted quite easily if you are stepping through your program - It will save you a lot of time as it will be much faster to detect this error on your own instead of writing the question here.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is in this line

```
 adaptersList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
```

it should be replaced with

```
adaptersList.item(0).getTextContent();
```

in order to give you that pathname.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly to read a file:

```
public class FileRead {
    static String string = File.separator;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("C:"+string+"myProject"+string+"adapters.xml");
        System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
}
```

Then try to test below code will help you to get file Name from xml:

```
NodeList nodeListData = xmlTableName.getElementsByTagName("properties");
for (int k = 0; k < nodeListData.getLength(); k++) { // loop for properties
    Node nodeData = nodeListData.item(k);
    Element elementColumnDetails = (Element) nodeData;
    NodeList nodeListRow = elementColumnDetails.getElementsByTagName("property);
    for (int l = 0; l < nodeListRow.getLength(); l++) { // loop for property
        Node nodeRow = nodeListRow.item(l);
        Element elementRow = (Element) nodeRow;
        if(elementRow.getAttribute("filename")){
            filePath = elementRow.getTextContent().trim();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the question is different.. He cannot read the adapters.xml itself.

Comment: Problem mentioned two problem, 1. "I am trying to read in a file path from an XML file in java", 2. "I am getting a file not found exception"

Comment: @Suzon, this code works, thank you for this, however is there a way of also returning the content in the <class> node?

Comment: @Suzon In my code above, I was able to get the contents from the <class> node, ie. "adapters.CSVFileAdpater" and "adapter.SNMPFileAdapter". However now I am only getting the values from the <properties> node. Is there a way of getting the content from all of the nodes?

Comment: @Suzon, I changed my code above to what I am currently using to try and return the content of all of the nodes, however I am getting a FileNotFoundException when I run this. I have tried debugging and can't seem to figure out the problem